# AMFPHP vs ZendAMF

Tags: php, actionscript-3, zend-framework, amfphp

Is one 'better' than the other?
Doubt that since as I understand both are written by the same author, only Adobe 'officially' supports Zend.

My application is composed of 3 parts
1-an image editing tool allowing users to upload images, edit them, then post them to a server.
2-a publicly viewable gallery
3-a private 'admin' tool allowing the user to change their login settings and delete any uploaded images.

Are both Zend and AMFPHP equally robust and easy to implement when it comes to session registration and login?

Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Both AMFPHP and the Zend_Amf classes are written by the same person, but the current AMFPHP is an old (php4-based) codebase - the guts of the new ZF class will, according to his blog (link below), help form the basis of a new, updated AMFPHP.

> AMFPHP will be a fantastic fit for
>   beginner to intermediate developers
>   and when you need the horse power of a
>   framework check out what I feel is the
>   best one on the market Zend Framework.
>
> In summery: Need your clients IP or
>   some database information into
>   Flash/Flex in the next 15 minutes;
>   AMFPHP is your friend.
>
> If you’re going to change the world
>   with an application that is enterprise
>   ready and can leverage the wealth of
>   code in a robust framework then check
>   out Zend Framework. It may be a little
>   more work at first but in the end you
>   will be saying wow that is nice!
>
> http://wadearnold.com/blog/flash/amfphp/the-future-of-amfphp

Answer (score 1):

AMFPHP is 5x as fast.  AMFPHP was built by Patrick Mineault.  ZendAMF was supported by Adobe, and built by Wade Arnold.

http://gfxcomplex.com/video/zend-amf-vs-amph_amfphp-ftw/